# Producing Arabic PDF using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, arabic, wkhtmltopdf

I have issues when producing Arabic PDFs using wkhtmltopdf and C#.

below is my code as a sample

```
 string HTML = "مرحبا";
            Encoding utf = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.UTF8;
            byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(HTML);
            HTML = utf.GetString(unicodeBytes);
```

the result is ????? in pdf
i have tried `'-q -n --encoding UTF-8'`  parameter to wkhtmltopdf with no success even.
any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML string should have the correct charset and Content-Type:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: already tried this:
'<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><span style="font-family: Times New Roman;">مرحبا</span></body></html>'
didnt work

Comment: i think its encoding problem here, i tried to create a new html file using notepad with a utf-8 encoding and sent it to wkhtmltopdf engine it rendered it correctly, in my case i need to do the encoding in c# which is not working in my case

Comment: Remove the above encoding conversion lines and test it again. strings in c# are Unicode+ you can try https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp

Comment: same result.., for some reason the conversion is not working, the default encoding supposed to be Unicode and iam trying to convert it to be UTF-8 with no success, even wkHtmltoPdf --encoding utf-8 seems it do nothing either

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to look at a few arabic websites and try to convert with pdfcrowd or htm2pdf.co.uk - they both use wkhtmltopdf and just take the page as input.

Whatever is in that page (so the format of that string) is what you pass to wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: pdfcrowd rendered the word correctly, htm2pdf didn't, still haven't a solution here

Answer (score 0):

The only way i managed to render Arabic characters by creating a temp HTML input file and send it to wkhtmltopdf engine

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>
       مرحبا
</body>
</html>
```

It worked fine with me wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 
in C# just save the HTML string inside  temporary html file and run wkhtmltopdf command 
 after that remove the temp html file

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help to someone else.

I was using a custom font for arabic which was not installed on my server.

Had to install it (+ using encoding utf-8) only then it worked..